# JSON Object Transformation into specific Javascript Array or JSON Object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, javascript-objects

So I have this JSON Object. Let's call it var `dataFetched`

```
var dataFetched = {
    "status": "ok",
    "count": 4,
    "count_total": 4,
    "pages": 1,
    "posts": [
    {
      "id": 57,
      "type": "keyword",
      "slug": "crime-scene-investigation-csi",
      "url": "http://keyjargon.com/keyword/crime-scene-investigation-csi/",
      "status": "publish",
      "title": "Crime Scene Investigation (CSI)",
      "title_plain": "Crime Scene Investigation (CSI)",
      "content": "",
      "excerpt": "",
      "date": "2015-11-07 05:01:51",
      "modified": "2015-11-07 05:01:51",
      "categories": [
        {
          "id": 8,
          "slug": "law",
          "title": "Law",
          "description": "",
          "parent": 0,
          "post_count": 1
        }
      ],
      "tags": [

      ],
      "author": {
        "id": 1,
        "slug": "admin",
        "name": "admin",
        "first_name": "",
        "last_name": "",
        "nickname": "admin",
        "url": "",
        "description": ""
      },
      "comments": [

      ],
      "attachments": [

      ],
      "comment_count": 0,
      "comment_status": "closed",
      "custom_fields": {

      }
    },
    {
      "id": 50,
      "type": "keyword",
      "slug": "fx",
      "url": "http://keyjargon.com/keyword/fx/",
      "status": "publish",
      "title": "FX",
      "title_plain": "FX",
      "content": "",
      "excerpt": "",
      "date": "2015-11-05 10:07:17",
      "modified": "2015-11-05 10:22:10",
      "categories": [
        {
          "id": 3,
          "slug": "business",
          "title": "Business",
          "description": "",
          "parent": 0,
          "post_count": 2
        }
      ],
      "tags": [

      ],
      "author": {
        "id": 1,
        "slug": "admin",
        "name": "admin",
        "first_name": "",
        "last_name": "",
        "nickname": "admin",
        "url": "",
        "description": ""
      },
      "comments": [

      ],
      "attachments": [

      ],
      "comment_count": 0,
      "comment_status": "closed",
      "custom_fields": {

      }
    },
    {
      "id": 48,
      "type": "keyword",
      "slug": "common-core",
      "url": "http://keyjargon.com/keyword/common-core/",
      "status": "publish",
      "title": "Common CORE",
      "title_plain": "Common CORE",
      "content": "",
      "excerpt": "",
      "date": "2015-11-05 10:06:40",
      "modified": "2015-11-07 04:58:06",
      "categories": [
        {
          "id": 2,
          "slug": "technology",
          "title": "Technology",
          "description": "",
          "parent": 0,
          "post_count": 3
        }
      ],
      "tags": [

      ],
      "author": {
        "id": 1,
        "slug": "admin",
        "name": "admin",
        "first_name": "",
        "last_name": "",
        "nickname": "admin",
        "url": "",
        "description": ""
      },
      "comments": [

      ],
      "attachments": [

      ],
      "comment_count": 0,
      "comment_status": "closed",
      "custom_fields": {

      }
    },
    {
      "id": 46,
      "type": "keyword",
      "slug": "api",
      "url": "http://keyjargon.com/keyword/api/",
      "status": "publish",
      "title": "API",
      "title_plain": "API",
      "content": "",
      "excerpt": "",
      "date": "2015-11-05 10:06:19",
      "modified": "2015-11-05 10:21:47",
      "categories": [
        {
          "id": 2,
          "slug": "technology",
          "title": "Technology",
          "description": "",
          "parent": 0,
          "post_count": 3
        }
      ],
      "tags": [

      ],
      "author": {
        "id": 1,
        "slug": "admin",
        "name": "admin",
        "first_name": "",
        "last_name": "",
        "nickname": "admin",
        "url": "",
        "description": ""
      },
      "comments": [

      ],
      "attachments": [

      ],
      "comment_count": 0,
      "comment_status": "closed",
      "custom_fields": {

      }
      }
      ]
}
```

I want to rearrange this result to link the Category title :

```
dataFetched.posts[i].categories[0].title
```

to the Post title :

```
dataFetched.post[i].title
```

so that each category displays  all the posts titles related to it. I want my object (whether multi-demmensional array or another object) to be able to retrieve all the Posts titles related to the category.

Maybe something like this :

```
   [Category1: {Post_titleA, PostTitleB, PostTitleC}, Category2: {PostTileF, PostTileX}, etc ] where each category can retrieve all its posts.( The format does not matter as long the Object with Category title X can retrieve all posts titles that belong to it ).
```

How do I do this in Javascript ? The result variable is not static but its format is the same as the one posted  here.

This is what I tried so far.

```
  // Function to sort unique values of an array
  function sort_unique(arr) {
      arr = arr.sort(function (a, b) { return a*1 - b*1; });
      var ret = [arr[0]];
      for (var i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) { // start loop at 1 as element 0 can never be a duplicate
        if (arr[i-1] !== arr[i]) {
            ret.push(arr[i]);
        }
     }
     return ret;
 }

 //Define two arrays to be used for categories and Keywords
 var keywords = [];
 var industries = [];

  //Fill up the categories(Industries) array and the keywords one
  for ( var i = 0, iLen = dataFetched.count; i < iLen; i++) {

    keywords[i] = dataFetched.posts[i].title;
    industries[i] = dataFetched.posts[i].categories[0].title;
  }

  // Sort and eliminate duplication of category and keyword names
  keywords = sort_unique(keywords);
  industries =  sort_unique(industries);

  // Now time for trouble: Define a multi-dimmensional array that links each category/industry to its keywords **This is where I AM STUCK**
  ind = new Array;
  for(i=0; i<industries.length;i++){
    ind[i] = new Array;
  }     
  for(i=0;i<dataFetched.count;i++){
    ind[i][0]= dataFetched.posts[i].categories[0].title;        
    for(j=0;j<dataFetched.count;j++){
        var count  = ind[i].length;
        if(ind[i][0] == dataFetched.posts[j].categories[0].title){
            ind[i][count] = dataFetched.posts[j].title;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: what code have you written to solve the problem?

Comment: Please include what you have already tried doing, we're not here to do things for you: only to help you do it. Might I also suggest that - if possible - you create the filters on the server (PHP, SQL)? It would be much better for the user as the downloaded data will be significantly smaller.

Comment: Thanks, I added what I tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to create object with categories. As a result all entries can be accessed by category name and you do not need to sort them to have unique titles:

```
var posts = dataFetched.posts;
var cat = {};

posts.forEach(
    function(p) {
        p.categories.forEach(            
            function(c) {
                if (!cat[c.title])
                    cat[c.title] = [];
                cat[c.title].push(p.title);
            });
    });

console.log(cat);
```

Output for your example:

```
Object {Law: Array[1], Business: Array[1], Technology: Array[2]}
```

Each category title is a key in this object and the arrays of posts are values of those keys.

Answer (score 1):

The output example you showed is wrong, in JS there's no object like

```
[Category1: {Post_titleA, PostTitleB, PostTitleC}, Category2: {PostTileF, PostTileX}, etc ]
```

The most similar thing you can get is a JSON object like this:

```
{
  "Category1" : ["Post_titleA", "PostTitleB", "PostTitleC"],
  "Category2" : ["PostTileF", "PostTileX"],
  //etc..
}
```

In order to achieve this, you can use the following function:

```
function getTitlesByCategory (json) {
    var result = {}
    json.posts.map(function (post) {
        post.categories.map(function (category) {
            result[category.title] = result[category.title] || [];
            result[category.title].push(post.title);
        });
    });

    return result;
}
```